# Atribute warning

Tags: android-sdk, android-layout

При использовании layout_marginVertical выходит предупреждение attribute layout_marginVertical is only used in API Level 26 ang higher (current min is 15).
У меня вопрос, то есть на устройствах API < 26 этот атрибут будет игнорироваться  и его лучше заменить на Top/Bottom ?

Upd: В autoSizeTextType выдаётся то же самое предупреждение, использование layout_marginVertical избежать легко, а какая есть альтернатива autoSizeTextType ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Совершенно верно, если вы пишите для версии ниже, чем 26, лучше использовать `marginTop`/`marginBottom`.

Для того, чтобы использовать `autoSizeTextType` в такой низкой версии API, существует специальная библиотека обратной совместимости (Android Support Library), которая позволяет использовать функции написанные для более поздних версий API в старых.

Включаете её в `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
   ....
   implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2'
}
```

и используете изменив префикс `android` на `app`

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
```

P.S. у вас выставлена довольно страя версия API, возможно стоит пересмотреть и повысить уровень SDK, это избавит вас от лишнего кода и минифицирует само приложение за счёт того, что не надо будет соблюдать такую давнюю совместимость.

Посмотреть процент использования различных версий Android, можно на официальном сайте https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards